# Python3 webserver communicate between threads for IRC bot

Tags: python, django, multithreading, irc

I've read a lot of documentation about Threading, Queuing, Pooling etc. but still couldn't figure out how to solve my problem.
Here's the situation :
I built a python3 Django application that's served by cherrypy. The application is basically another IRC client. When I use the GUI to run my code the first time, an IRC bot is launched through a deamon Thread and listens to events. My problem is the following : how do I send data to that thread (and my bot), for instance to tell him to join a second channel ? When I run my code a second time, obviously a new instance of my bot is created, along with a new server connection. I need a way to communicate with my bot through GUI interaction. Right now the only way I had to make my bot react the specific things is by reading the database. Some other GUI action would change that database. Which is a bad system.

Here is the relevant code that starts my bot.

```
def DCC_deamonthread(c, server, nickname, upload):
    try:
        c.connect(server, 6667, nickname)
        c.start()
    except irc.client.ServerConnectionError as x:
        log("error" + str(x)).write()
        upload.status, upload.active = "Error during connection", False
        upload.save()

def upload_file(filename, rec_nick, pw):
    global upload
    Upload_Ongoing.objects.all().delete()
    upload = Upload_Ongoing(filename=filename,status="Connecting to server...", active=True)
    upload.save()
    irc.client.ServerConnection.buffer_class.encoding = 'latin-1'
    c = DCCSend(filename, rec_nick, pw)
    server = "irc.rizon.net"
    nickname = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(10))
    t = threading.Thread(target=DCC_deamonthread, args=(c, server, nickname, upload))
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as you noticed, that you spawn a new thread/bot each time there is an upload. A possible solution would be to rewrite your code to do something like this:

```
event_queue = multiprocessing.Queue() # Events that will be sent to the IRC bot thread

def irc_bot_thread():
    bot = connect_to_irc()

    for event in event_queue:
        bot.handle_event(event)

threading.Thread(target=irc_bot_thread).start()

def upload_file(filename, rec_nick, pw):
    # Django stuff

    event_queue.push(<necessary data for use by the bot>)
```

Comment: Will event_queue not be overwritten by the new execution ?

Comment: Well a new event_queue is definitely created. But indeed, by having my bot reading event_queue in a loop, then importing event_queue in another thread, I managed to properly send data via the GUI to that first bot. Which is what I was looking for. Is there another possible way ? (I will validate as soon as I managed to completely implement the solution).

Comment: Also, is there an efficient way to read queue items without removing items ? Is there another similar object that allows data persistency ?

Comment: 1. it depends if the module is reloaded at each execution (PHP/CGI style) or preserve (WSGI style). I never tried, but it seems more logically to me that cherrypy does the second.

Comment: 2. An other possible way would have to run a bot separately with each own HTTP server (Limnoria does have one) and make the Django script make an HTTP request to the bot.

Comment: 3. You should ask that as an other SO question. You'll get more/better responses. I would suggest a `list` with a `Lock`, but there may be better ways.